# node-postgres vs sequelize performance

Tags: node.js, performance, sequelize.js, node-postgres

I tried to test simple node-postgresql queries performance and sequelize models. I have used soapUI and the result is that sequelize works quite faster than simple driver(and the difference is even bigger if I use more and more virtual users). I test it all on localhost and local database. Changing max parameter in Pool definition in node-postgresql hasn't changed anything. Is it really worth using sequelize than simple queries if we speak about performance and in what way can sequelize improve it? (or if I do smth  wrong, how can I fix it in order to get better performance on native queries) 
I use simple select statement with two tables with same fields but in different databases
node-postgresql

```
const client = await this.pool.connect();
    const [user] = (await client.query(
      'select * from users where username=$1', [username],
    )).rows;
    client.release(true);
```

sequelize

```
const user = await this.UserModel.findOne({ where: { username } });
```

UserModel is smth like this

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('user', {
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: {
      msg: 'Данный пользователь уже существует',
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: {
        msg: 'Поле пароль не может быть пустым',
      },
    },
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: {
        msg: 'Должна присутствовать картинка пользователя',
      },
    },
  },
  total_amount: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0,
  },
  createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
});
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEF2N.jpg - soapUI tests and results(first request uses node-postgresql, the second one - sequelize)

Comment: You need to provide more relevant data. We have no way of knowing how complex your queries are or how you tested the performance.

Comment: @ShaharHadas i added some info

Comment: is it the same connection string on both?

Comment: @ShaharHadas different local databases with the same tables and columns(so the only difference is database name)

Comment: can you create a small test project on github or any other online repo? with the sql init script or the postgres dump (that I can restore from)? I need to acutally debug your code to be able to assist.